# Columns don't stick together, even I already calculated the Grid system(Bootstrap) well

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to finish my own project. This section is a Blog page that gathers a lot of article cards.
The problem is, let's imagine there are 4 columns,
-the first is Col-6,
-the second is Col-4,
-the third is Col-2 and
-the fourth is Col-10.

The first and second are the highlighted articles

The third one is the sideline which shows writers( which is not important to the intention of this page, compared to article cards).

The fourth one is a group of less prioritized cards

My intention is to stick the First & Second to the Fourth. But, due to the length of the content inside the Third column, I couldn't stick the First and Second columns with the Fourth column together. you can see from my code below that there's a gap in between.
[image]

Here is my code
https://github.com/doublechai/tfwi/blob/main/knowledge_sharing.html

Please help.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/landingheart-the-animator/pen/rNyKvQg

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img width="60px" height="60px" src="LOGO" >ThoughtForward Institute</img>
        </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>  
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Devote this section for our GOD</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Our Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marketing Campaign</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Event Management</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hackathon Hunting</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Knowledge Sharing</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="万事先难后易" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Knowledge Sharing</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>What we wanna with chu</p>
  <hr>
  <p>ตลอดเวลาหลายปีที่ผ่านมาบุญของอาจารย์ได้เผยแพร่สู่นักเรียนมากหน้า หลายตา หลายวงการ Lorem ipsum It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="muscle.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
                <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
              </svg>
              <span>XXX</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary"><a href="https://www.google.com">Web Development</a></span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 465px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="muscle.jpeg" alt="..." style="width: 185px; height: 185px;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">Card title length is 100 words</h6>
              <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
                <p><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary"><a href="https://www.google.com">Web Development</a></span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
                  <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
                </svg>
                <span>XXX</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 465px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="muscle.jpeg" alt="..." style="width: 185px; height: 185px;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">Card title length is 100 words</h6>
              <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
                <p><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary"><a href="https://www.google.com">Web Development</a></span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
                  <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
                </svg>
                <span>XXX</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 465px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="muscle.jpeg" alt="..." style="width: 185px; height: 185px;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">Card title length is 100 words</h6>
              <div class="row position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
                <p><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary"><a href="https://www.google.com">Web Development</a></span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
                  <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
                </svg>
                <span>XXX</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
    
    
     
    
     
   
    
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>

<style>
  hr{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
  }

  a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

This is the codepen and this will solve your issue, if you find this helpful please accept as answer thank you.

Comment: basically your problem is the right most col-md-2 you have too many and it pushes the layout down and you got the gap.

Comment: But I still want to keep the Col-md-2 attached because it's also important to this page. Is there a way to solve this problem but still keep that section as well?

Comment: Layout the page with 3 col, just put your content under the col you want your content to have.